# Is it possible to define multiple bindings in the same service

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service.
Is it possible to define a WCF service to have mulitple bindings

like

Method1 - WSHttpbinding
Method2 - BasicHttpbinding
Method3 - NETTcpBinding

Thanks.

Comment: Its necessary to understanding that what role binding plays in overall communication. A brief description of [Understanding WCF Binding and Channel Stack](http://wcfanswers.blogspot.com/2012/06/understanding-wcf-bindings-and-channel.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't set a binding on method level.

What you can do: expose the entire service on multiple endpoints, where each endpoint is configured with a different binding (WsHttp, BasicHttp, Tcp, etc).